# What's the policy on editing at this site?

Tags: discussion, editing

I'm new to this great site. I know very little about cars, so I probably won't contribute much other than voting and editing, at least in the beginning.

The sites where I spend the most time are Gardening and Landscaping, and The Great Outdoors. At those sites, if a question can be made easier to read by improving things like punctuation, grammar, sentence structure and image formatting, we editors will do that. Titles are frequently re-worded to add details that better match the body of the question, and to turn them into questions rather than statements. We also add and/or remove tags when appropriate. In some cases, an editor provides links to outside sources of information referred to in the question. [This](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23474/does-my-very-young-eureka-lemon-tree-have-leaf-disease) is an example of a question I edited at GL. The goal is to respect the OP while making the question a bit more legible for future viewers.

Each site has its own personality, and I don't want to come in and start editing things that should be left alone. Would you be willing to clarify your policy here? Thank you!

I read [this](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246/editing-questions-answers-only-for-better-readability) meta post from 2013, which was helpful, but it doesn't seem to address everything I'm asking. However, if it's a duplicate, I apologize, and will be happy to delete this to get it out of your way!

Comment: Just do what you do @sue.   Thanks for contributing!  It's well received.   :-)

Comment: @DucatiKiller Thanks for the support. I appreciate it!

Comment: The reality is that we *need* more grammar policing.  A lot of our traffic is clearly coming from thumb typing chatspeak into a tiny web interface.  That's sometimes okay for the question right now but what about the next person with the exact same problem?  Better posts are more searchable == better for all of us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I completely agree with Larry (Move more comments link to top) about this. Maybe to expand on this a little, improvement to a question to make it better is great. Have no fear in doing so. Remember, even the answers can be approved upon. Most of us are a bunch of knuckleheads who cannot string two complete sentences together. About the only thing I'd suggest is, if you see things which are local color you'd hear from England English versus American English.

For instance:

```
America     England
Tire        Tyre
Color       Colour
Aluminum    Aluminium
```

This list is not, obviously, a complete list, but hopefully gives you the right idea. Each word is completely acceptable and most anyone can read one versus the other and understand the meaning. You will notice under the tag for [tire](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tire), tyre is a synonym. Again, either would be completely acceptable, but it was put under a single tag so questions could be more easily found.

What does all this mean? We are more than happy to accept any contribution which you can bring. I'm sure the way they do things over on GL.SE or wherever you may roam on SE is going to be more than acceptable.

Thanks for being here!!!

Comment: This is great. I appreciate the welcome and the clarification. I'm American so that's always my first tendency, but I'll watch out.  I'll spend some time looking around before doing anything drastic of course! People from here, including you, have helped GL (and me!) in a huge way, so if I can contribute at all over here, I'll be glad.

Comment: @Sue - Again, welcome! We are glad to have new people in what ever manner they can participate. J.Musser has had very good things to say about you. I try to help on other sites as well, but wrenching is truly my first love.

Comment: Also don't forget the chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop  That's a great place to ask for clarification or to pose a possible edit.  There's always a few dingdongs in there with something to say.  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

What you do on the other sites would be fine here. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I'll even learn something, or at least I'll have a new place to send my husband!

Comment: @Sue, just so we're clear: our mission is to teach people like you (who checked us out on your own).  This is definitely an area where a little basic knowledge will take you a long way.  Hubby can fend for himself....  ;-)